# std::thread and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, rvalue-reference

I wanted to have some kind of delegator class. Shortened version of my approach is below and it's main functionality is to start new thread doing some thing (in this example it prints text every second):

```
void Flusher::start(){
    m_continue.store(true);

    m_thread = std::thread([](std::atomic<bool>& shouldContinue){
        while(shouldContinue.load()){
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            std::cout << "sec passed" << std::endl;
        }}, std::ref<std::atomic<bool>>(m_continue)
    );
}
```

My concern is, that std::thread constructor has following signature:

```
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

So it takes rvalue reference as the first and second argument. If it's so, then I should not use `shouldContinue` after passing it to the `std::thread` constructor as it was **moved**.

Of course I want to have control over this function and therefore I want to use shouldContinue in a caller thread to stop called function. For obvious reasons I do not want to make this variable global.

I think, that `std::ref` makes some magic there, but I am still not sure how does it work (I saw `std::ref` in some examples when creating new thread).

I tried to not care at all about the fact, this is rvalue reference and I used `shouldContinue` later on and nothing crashed, but I fear this is simply undefined behavior. Could anyone tell if above code is correct and if not, how to do this correctly?

Comment: it's a *forwarding reference*, not an rvalue reference

Comment: I have not heard of this. I will check this out

Comment: FWIW, `std::ref<std::atomic<bool>>(m_continue)` should be shortened to `std::ref(m_continue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special type deduction rule when && is used with templates.

Check this out for a really good explanation:

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/

```
template <class T>
void func(T&& t) {
}
```

"When && appears in a type-deducing context, T&& acquires a special meaning. When func is instantiated, T depends on whether the argument passed to func is an lvalue or an rvalue. If it's an lvalue of type U, T is deduced to U&. If it's an rvalue, T is deduced to U:"

```
func(4);            // 4 is an rvalue: T deduced to int

double d = 3.14;
func(d);            // d is an lvalue; T deduced to double&

float f() {...}
func(f());          // f() is an rvalue; T deduced to float

int bar(int i) {
  func(i);          // i is an lvalue; T deduced to int&
}
```

Also, reference collapsing rule is a good read.

Comment: There should be U&& if rvalue I guess. Please edit your post and I'll make it as accepted one. Thank you very much :)

Comment: U refers to int,float or any other type..So, I guess it's correct.It could be T also, but to differentiate between the callee and the template argument, I guess U is used here.

Comment: T is deduced to U: -> T is deduced to U&&. I mean this line. Is this correct?

Comment: added examples.the type deduction results into pass by value or pass by reference..based on the callee parameter type is rvalue or lvalue.